# SystemSettingsBroker.exe using millions of handles for no apparent reason

Tags: windows-11

Here is a screenshot from task manager:

[image]

One can see that `SystemSettingsBroker.exe` has 12.8M handles. This is on Windows 11 (22H2). I think that around 16M handles is the max, and it could lead to system crash?

Anyone a clue what may be the cause?

Comment: I believe it could lead to system crash. I noticed that if I leave it at that, my system just suddenly reboots randomly. When I started terminating any process consuming more than 10k handles my PC no longer crashes randomly. Not sure why. My current uptime is now 20 days and counting.